# How do I properly configure my app to use the Django phonenumber field module?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, validation, phone-number

I'm using the Django 2.0, Python 3.7, and the Django PhoneNumber field -- https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field and have set up my model thusly ...

```
class Coop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    type = models.ForeignKey(CoopType, on_delete=None)
    address = AddressField(on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    web_site = models.TextField()
```

I have added this in my settings.py file ...

```
PHONENUMBER_DB_FORMAT="RFC3966"
```

However, when I submit my form using the following JSON ...

```
{
        "name": "3999",
        "type": {
            "name": "Coworking Space"
        },
        "address": {
            "street_number": "222",
            "route": "1212",
            "raw": "222 W. Merchandise Mart Plaza, Suite 1212",
            "formatted": "222 W. Merchandise Mart Plaza, Suite 1212",
            "latitude": 41.88802611,
            "longitude": -87.63612199,
            "locality": {
                "name": "Chicago",
                "postal_code": "60654",
                "state": 1
            }
        },
        "enabled": true,
        "phone": "303-234-1234",
        "email": null,
        "web_site": "http://www.1871.com/"
}
```

I get this error (a 400 response)  ...

```
{"phone":["The phone number entered is not valid."]}
```

How else can I configure my server to recognize my phone number format (or do I need to change the format)?

Comment: @kyore, Gave this a go but didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see three ways of achieving this:

**Option 1**

Use a [RegEx validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/validators/#django.core.validators.RegexValidator) inside your `PhoneNumberField`:

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
...
phone = PhoneNumberField(null=True, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$')])
```

---

**Option 2**

According to documentation, you can set the format to be `NATIONAL` and then set the region. As such, [you can use](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field/issues/207) in your settings:

```
PHONENUMBER_DB_FORMAT = 'NATIONAL'
PHONENUMBER_DEFAULT_REGION = 'US'
```

---

**Option 3**

Use a [RegEx validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/validators/#django.core.validators.RegexValidator), but change your field to be a `CharField`.

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
...
phone = models.CharField(null=True, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$')])
```

Comment: I went with option #2 and it's a winner.

Comment: Option #2 FTW. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

As documentation says:

> Recommended is one of the globally meaningful formats 'E164', 'INTERNATIONAL' or 'RFC3966'. 'NATIONAL' format require to set up PHONENUMBER_DEFAULT_REGION variabl

So you need to setup your default region. eg:  `PHONENUMBER_DEFAULT_REGION='US'` in your `settings.py`.

Comment: Tried adding "PHONENUMBER_DEFAULT_REGION='US'" to my settings.py file but I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regular expression to allow hyphen in between. It will allow these formats
* 123-456-7890
* 333-333-4444
* 1234567890
* 123456789
* 123-4567-890
* 14157059247

Regular expression `^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$`

Comment: Use the regular expression where?

Comment: @Dave, Near the modal and call that in field

Comment: Sry, I'm not understanding what you're describing.

Comment: @Dave `phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")`
**inside the model**
`phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, unique=True)
`